# How to get the icon for a MIME type?

Tags: gnome, gtk, mime-types, icons

How to get the icon for a MIME type?
I don't want to use `g_file_info_get_icon()` because its input parameter is a file, not a MIME type.

My use case:

I have a wrapper file which embeds a media object, I can get the MIME type of the media object and want to find the icon of the MIME type. And I don't want to dump the media object to a separate file to use `g_file_info_get_icon()`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `g_content_type_get_icon ()`?

You might need to call `g_content_type_from_mime_type ()` first.

[GContentType docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GContentType.html)